# Same output in return true and return false?

Tags: java, android, onkeydown

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web_view().canGoBack()) {
        web_view().goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I have this code and changing the `return true`to `return false` has the same effect. Can someone explain why?

Comment: What effect are you expecting, exactly? That is, what isn't working?

Comment: @MikeM. Everything is working fine, I am just wondering why changing the `return` from `true` to `false` and vice versa has the same effect...

Comment: If you just google it before asking here, it will help you more!

Answer (score 5):

From the [`View#onKeyDown docs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29),

> Returns
>   `boolean`  If you handled the event, return true. If you want to allow the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false.

The `return true`/`return false` doesn't affect you here. It affects the next receiver of the event. If you return true, the event won't be propagated to the next potential `onKeyDown` receiver.

Comment: Not just the next `onKeyDown`, any receiver, such as `onClick`.

Comment: @user13 `onClick` does not return any value.

Comment: @Rohan it does not, indeed. So?

Comment: @user13 can you please explain your first comment ? If `onClick` does not return a value, then how does it affect any other potential receivers ? And as far as I know, a `View` can only have a single `onClickListener`.

Comment: @Rohan I was not talking about `onClick` effecting other receivers but `onKeyDown` effecting `onClick`.